# calculate total column of visible row only c# winform

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have some row with three column  name  payement and Other payement. and i write this line to calculate the total of the two columns payement and other payement

```
  int sumDoit = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            int tmp = 0;
            int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString(), out tmp);
            sumDoit += tmp;
        }
        txtPayement.Text = sumDoit.ToString("");

        int sumRecu = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            int tmp = 0;
            int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value.ToString(), out tmp);
            sumRecu += tmp;
        }
        txtOtherpayement.Text = sumRecu.ToString("");
```

the problem with this lines that when i hide some rows it should calculate the total of visible rows only not all the rows. Any idea how can i adjust this line to get my goal? thankyou

Comment: As a side note: you should consider consolidating your two loops into one and calculating `sumDoit` and `sumRecu` simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
int sumDoit = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow rowItem in dataGridView1.Rows)
{ 
    if(rowItem.Visible){
       int tmp = 0;
       int.TryParse(rowItem.Cells[11].Value, out tmp);
       sumDoit += tmp;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I was going just to post same answer :)